# share files and functions through multiple projects

Tags: python

it's a kind of open question but please bear with me.
I am working on several projects (mainly with pandas) and I have created my standard approach to manage them:
 1. create a main folder for all files in a project
 2. create a data folder
 3. have all the output in another folder
and so on.

One of my main activities is data cleaning, and in order to standardize it I have created a dictionary file where I store the various translation of the same entity, e.g. USA, US, United States, and so on, so that the files I am producing are consistent.

Every time I create a new project, I copy the dictionary file in the data directory and then:

```
xls = pd.ExcelFile(r"data/dictionary.xlsx")
df_area = xls.parse("area")
```

and after, to translate the country name into my standard, I call:

```
join_column, how_join = "country",  "inner"
df_ct = pd.concat([
    df_ct.merge(df_area, left_on=join_column, right_on="country_name", how=how_join),
    df_ct.merge(df_area, left_on=join_column, right_on="alternative01", how=how_join),
```

and finally I check that I am not losing an record with a miss-join.
Over and over the same thing.

I would like to have a way to remove all this unnecessary cut and paste (of the file and of the code). Also, the file I used on the first projects are already deprecated and I need to update them (and sometime the code) when I need to process new data. Sometimes I also lose track of where is the latest dictionary file! Overall it's a lot of maintenance, which I believe might be saved.
Creating my own package is the way to go or is it a little too much ambitious? 
Is there another shortcut? Overall it's not a lot of code, but multiplied by several projects.

Thanks for any insight, your time going through this is appreciated.

Comment: The easiest solution is to put all files (source code, excel files, etc) shared by all projects in a folder named `shared` (or whatever name you prefer) at the same level where you have all your project folders. So for each project, these shared resources could be accessed by `../shared`

Comment: thanks. sorry just to clarify, you mean to create a python script that define the dictionary function, then executing that script at the beginning of  my script the function become available in the calling script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I decided to create my own package.
It required some time so I am happy to share the details about the process (I run python on jupyter and windows).

1. The first step is to decide where to store the code.
   In my case it was C:\Users\my_user\Documents
2. You need to add this directory to the list of the directories where python is looking for packages. this is achieved running the following statement:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\my_user\\Documents")
   ```

In order to run the above statement each time you start python, it must be included into a file in the directory (this directory might vary depending on your installation):

```
C:\Users\my_user\.ipython\profile_default\startup
```

the file can be named "00-first.py" ("50-middle.py" or "99-last.py" will also work)

3. To verify everything is working, restart python and run the command:

   ```
   print(sys.path)
   ```

   you should be able to see your directory at this point.
4. create a folder with the package name in your directory, and a subfolder (I prefer not to have code in the main package folder)

   ```
   C:\Users\my_user\Documents\my_package\my_subfolder
   ```
5. put an empty file named "_ _init__.py" (note that there should be no space between underscores, but I do not know how to achieve it with the editor) in each of the two folders: my package and my_subfolder. At this point you should be able already to import your empty package from python
       import my_package as my_pack
6. inside my_subfolder create a file (my_code.py) which will store the actual code

   ```
   def my_function(name):
       print("Hallo " + name)
   ```
7. modify the outer _ _init__.py file to include shortcuts. Add the following:
       from my_package.my_subfolder.my_code import my_function
8. You should be able now to run the following in python:
       my_pack.my_function("World!")

Hope you find it useful!